# Syntax PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys I am new to PHP and Laravel, I came across this syntax:

```
 return ($this->someObject)($param1, $param2);
```

but I can't understand it, would someone be so kind as to explain it to a newbie in php? consider that:
I understand the OOP and I understand that someObject is part of a dependency injection and its class contains a single method called __invoke, but I don't understand why parentheses are used like that when trying to use a method, I also understand (if I'm wrong please correct me) that the methods called __invoke work as a kind of single method and are executed automatically when using the instance of your class (I think I read about it in the laravel documentation), is that why the parentheses are used in such a strange way?, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: where did you see this, btw?

Comment: It is part of a library that I must modify

Comment: this is because they are trying to call the invokable object ... if they didn't have the parenthesis around `$this->someObject` it would be `$this->someObject(...)` which would be trying to call a method named `someObject` not referencing a parameter named `someObject` [which just happens to be invokable] ... the parentheses resolve the statement to the property and the next parentheses is the actual method call on the resolution of that statement